# ASP.NET MVC5: RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want that if the user doesn't have access to a specific page, the will redirect to this page **"ErrorAccessPage.cshtml"**. This page doesn't have any controller. It is in the Folder name **Shared**.

Here's the logic:

```
if (user has access){
    return View();
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("//how to input the page here?");
}
```

Update:

After I changed the code to this:

```
if (moduleViewModel.CanRead == true){
    return View();
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("~/Shared/ErrorAccessPage.cshtml");
}
```

[image]

Comment: `return View("yourViewName");`

Comment: return RedirectToAction("~/Shared/ErrorAccessPage");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `RedirectToAction` without a controller, since the Action must live on a controller.  That said, you can redirect to a "plain" html file:

```
Redirect("~/Shared/ErrorAccessPage.html");
```

or you can return the view directly from your current controller action without redirecting at all:

```
return View("~/Shared/ErrorAccessPage.cshtml");
```

As for your updated error message, since you are trying to access a view outside of the Views folder, MVC is prohibiting the serving up of the file.  You have two options:

Move the view inside of the views folder:

```
return View("~/Views/Shared/ErrorAccessPage.cshtml");
```

Allow MVC to serve up views from outside of the Views folder by adding:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

to your web.config

For security and consistency reasons, the former is recommended.

Comment: No, your answer is enough. I really want to up vote your answer but I don't have enough reputation to do that. So, just cheers for now. -Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use method `View("ErrorAccessPage")` to show your page.

`RedirectToAction()` will be search for a controller action not a view. If it find a controller action it passes the execution control to that matched controller action.

If you want to just show a view you can use `View("view_name")`. Because it will search a html, aspx or cshtml file under the directory **View->Your_Current_Controller_Name** and **View->Shared** in your solution and just display it.

```
if (user has access){
    return View();
}
else
{
    return View("ErrorAccessPage");
}
```

So, your final code will be,

Hope this will help you.